# Apache Spark - Implementing a distributed QuadTree

Tags: scala, apache-spark, data-structures, pyspark, distributed

I am really, really, new to Apache Spark.

I am working on implementing Approximate LOCI (or ALOCI), an anomaly detection algorithm, on a distributed way over Spark. This algorithm is based on storing points in a QuadTree that is used to find a point's number of neighbors.

I know exactly how QuadTrees work. In fact, I have implemented such a structure in Java recently. But I am completely lost as far as it concerns the way that such a structure can work in a distributed way over Spark.

Something similar to what I need can be found in Geospark.

https://github.com/DataSystemsLab/GeoSpark/tree/b2b6f1d7f0015d5c9d663a7b28d5e1bb1043c413/core/src/main/java/org/datasyslab/geospark/spatialPartitioning/quadtree

GeoSpark uses in many cases a PointRDD class, that extends a SpatialRDD class which I can see that uses the QuadTree that can be found in the link above to partition the Spatial objects. That is what I understood, at least, in theory.

In practice, I still cannot figure this out. Let's say for example that I have millions of records in a csv and I want to read and load them in a QuadTree.

I could read a csv to an RDD, but then what? How does this RDD logically connects to the QuadTree I am trying to build?

Of course, I don't expect a working solution here. I just need the logic here to fill the gap in my mind. How do I implement a distributed QuadTree and how do I use it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sadly there are no answers to this, but here I am two weeks later with a working solution. Not 100% sure if it is the right approach here, though.

I created a class named Element and turned each line of my csv to an RDD[Element]. I then created a serializable class named QuadNode which has a List[Elements] and an Array[String] of size 4. On adding elements  to a node, these elements are added in the node's List. If the list get more than X elements (20 in my case), the node breaks into 4 children and the elements are sent to the children. Finally, I created a class QuadTree which has an RDD[QuadNodes] among its rest properties. Every time a node breaks to children then these children-nodes are added in the tree's RDD.

In a non-functional language, each node would have 4 pointers, one for each child. Since, we are in a distributed environment this approach could not work. So, I gave each node a unique Id. Root node has an id = "0". Root's nodes have ids "00", "01", "02" and "03". Node-"00" children have ids "000","001","002","003". In this way if we want to find all the descendants of a node, we filter our tree's RDD[QuadNode] by checking if nodes' ids startWith out node id. Reversing this logic helps us to find a node's parent node.

This is how I implemented my QuadTree, at least for now. If someone knows a better way of implementing this I would love to hear his/her opinion.